# SQL Select a distinct row based on two columns which has min value in third column

Tags: sql, postgresql

EDIT: I'm using PostgresSQL

My query needs to return all the unique rows for the id column and the type column. When there are multiple rows with the same id and type it will return the row with the smallest value in the time column.

```
SELECT id, type, value FROM TableName 
GROUP BY MIN(time)
ORDER BY id ASC, type ASC
```

This is what I have so far but I feel like I'm using GROUP BY the wrong way

Comment: please tag the database you are using.

Comment: In some dbms this sentence is not correct. Please tag your dbms.

Comment: My bad. I edited the OP

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to mark the rows within each combination of id and type with the smallest time having *rn = 1*, then use *WHERE* clause to filter the table:

```
SELECT id, type, value FROM
(SELECT id, type, value, 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id, type ORDER BY time) AS rn 
 FROM TableName) a
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres support `distinct on`.  This is usually the most efficient way to do what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, type) id, type, value
FROM TableName 
ORDER BY id, type, time ;
```